# matlab - questions about slope (derivattives)

Tags: matlab, math

I have a function `y=0.05*x.^2 - 0.24*x+(1/(x.^2+1))`.

1) I want to find the slope for x [-4,4] , so I do

```
syms x;
y=0.05*x.^2 - 0.24*x+(1/(x.^2+1))
der=diff(y)
matrix=subs(der,x,-4:4)
```

and I am finding the values of y'(x) for the different values of x.
(the result is : -0.6123   -0.4800   -0.2800    0.1600   -0.2400   -0.6400   -0.2000         0 0.1323)

Now, I want to determine all the peaks and valleys of the slope.
To find this , I take from the results that for x=3 i have y'(3)=0 => I have a critical point.

So, to find the peaks and valleys I need to see the sign left and right from point 3,right?
So, for x=-4,-2 =>valley , x=-2,-1 peak, x=-1,0 valley, x=0,2 valley , x=2,4 peak.

Is this right? Also,for plotting the slope I use `ezplot(der)` ?

2) I need to find the drop of the slope (difference between largest ans smallest value of y).
How can I find that, since y is symbolic?

3) If I want to find the slope in degrees, how can I do it?

4) If I have x and t data (position and time) and I want to compute the velocity, I just do?

```
v=x./t;
result=diff(v)
```

--------UPDATE---------------

For my last question i have:

```
time=linspace(0,1.2,13);
position=[41,52,61,69,73,75,74,66,60,55,43,27,27];

v=position./time;
vel=diff(v)

plot(time,vel)
```

But the problem is that vel vector results in 1x12 vector instead 1x13.Why is that?

Comment: `time(1) = 0;` which evidentely yields to `Inf` when calculating `v`. that explains why `vel` has 12 values instead of 13.

Comment: @fpe:And is there a way to make the plot?

Comment: avoiding `time(1)` which leads to `vel(1) = Inf`, you may call `plot(time(2:end),vel)`. btw,what `vel` represents? Seems to me it's an acceleration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really familiar with matlab, but I am going to give you some pointers with respect to the math. You define:

```
 y(x) = 0.025*x^2 - 0.24*x + (1/(x^2+1))
```

This is the blue curve in the added picture. We can take the derivative with respect to x to find:

```
 dy(x)/dx = 0.1*x - 0.24 - (2*x/(1+x^2)^2)
```

which is the purple curve. I do not really know what you mean with 'peaks' and 'valleys' but if you mean maxima and minima of `y(x)` respectively than your answer is incorrect. Maxima or minima in `y(x)` can be found by finding the values of `x` where the derivative `dy/dx` is zero. You can confirm this by looking at the picture. At `x=3` red curve is zero because `y(x)` has a minimum there. (Note that by finding a point `x` where the derivative is zero, does not tell you whether it is in fact a maximum or a minimum, just that it is an extremum).

[image: Plot of y(x) and the derivative with respect to x, dy/dx]

2) You can find the drop in the curve as follows. First determine the values of `x` of the maximum and the minimum `x1` and `x2` (i.e. solve `dy(x)/dx == 0`). The drop is then `abs( y(x1) - y(x2) )`.

3) Officially the curve does not have one slope - it is curved so its slope varies with `x`. However if you mean the average slope between the max and min than it is simple geometry. You have the displacement in `x` and `y`, look into the function `tan` and you will be able to find the answer.

Good luck